# How to properly use Function.InvokeAfter to delay Power Query Processing of my entire query in Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I am trying to delay a Power Query in Excel from running by about 25 seconds (Lets call it Query 2).  This is to allow another query (Query 1) to pull data from an external source first.  Query 2 only references internal table data and completes much faster than Query 1, meaning it misses most of the data updates.  The result is I end up using "Refresh All" twice to pick up all the data.  This is fine, but annoying and I believe can be solved by using the advanced editor in Power Query.

I can't use VBA code to resolve this for the particular spreadsheet (need to maintain .xlsx).

My research online has indicated that Function.InvokeAfter can be used to accomplish this.

I know you need to call all of the query actions as a function, but I'm having trouble with the syntax.

Here is my code snippet...it works, but does not delay the query as desired.  I believe the problem is the way the Let command is processed (non sequentially).  I'm sure the syntax is off as I'm a bit of a neophyte in the advanced editor in Power Query.  Note I don't care about the getting time as text, I was just trying to do "something" to make the query delay.  I've tried referencing the source line as the function but then I get an error about can't return a table as type function.

```
let
    GetTimeAsText = ()=> DateTime.ToText(DateTime.LocalNow()), 
    Output = GetTimeAsText() & " " & Function.InvokeAfter(GetTimeAsText, #duration(0,0,0,25)),
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ReviewHist"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Download Dt", type datetime}, {"LTCF", type text}, {"Other Monitored Settings", type text}}),
    #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Changed Type", ReviewPrep}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Appended Query",{{"Download Dt", type date}}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Changed Type1", {"Download Dt"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Duplicates",{{"Download Dt", Order.Descending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need one query to finish before another, but add a reference in Query1 to Query2, thus forcing Query2 to finish before Query1. You don't actually have to use the data being referenced.

```
//Query2 code
let Source2=Query1,
Source=blah blah,
#nextstep=(Source,
```

Comment: Reason: Query 2 needs updated data from query 1 .  Query 1 takes about. 20 seconds longer than query 2 to complete.  Thus query 2 is running before all of the updated data is available from query 1.  This results in me having to run it twice to properly update all of the tables

Answer (score 0):

It is awkward that your queries don't automatically wait until a dependent query is done because that is the default behavior.  Only thing thing I can think of is that you created formulas/columns directly in the Excel Table and they reference an Excel Table that the other query loads into Excel.  If this is the case it would be better to just create all the logic within Power Query.

Below is an example of how to use Function.Invoke after.  Your query has no parameters so you can create a function with no variables.

```
let
    query = () =>
    let
        Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ReviewHist"]}[Content],
        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Download Dt", type datetime}, {"LTCF", type text}, {"Other Monitored Settings", type text}}),
        #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Changed Type", ReviewPrep}),
        #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Appended Query",{{"Download Dt", type date}}),
        #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Changed Type1", {"Download Dt"}),
        #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Duplicates",{{"Download Dt", Order.Descending}})
    in
        #"Sorted Rows",
    delay = Function.InvokeAfter(query,#duration(0,0,0,25)) 
in
    delay
```

You can also delay a single step as long as referenced in your very next step.

```
let
    Source = Function.InvokeAfter( 
        () => Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ReviewHist"]}[Content],
        #duration(0,0,0,25)),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(delay,{{"Download Dt", type datetime}, {"LTCF", type text}, {"Other Monitored Settings", type text}}),
    #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Changed Type", ReviewPrep}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Appended Query",{{"Download Dt", type date}}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Changed Type1", {"Download Dt"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Duplicates",{{"Download Dt", Order.Descending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

Comment: No, pivot tables are not the issue.  This is two queries, one piggy backs off the other.  Background refresh does not resolve this

Comment: See edits for example.  The example does not run the entire thing until 25 seconds.  Probably could technically just do it for a single step instead of the entire query so that you can still edit your query.

Comment: Your code works...It does delay the execution of the query as desired.  But now its throwing the error about “Formula.Firewall: Query 'QueryName' (step 'StepName') references other queries or steps and so may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination.”  It was not doing that before, so I'm not sure what about the changes did this.  I tried resolving that error by following steps at https://excelguru.ca/power-query-errors-please-rebuild-this-data-combination/, but it resulted in the delayed query running "first" again, undoing the progress of your code

Comment: Home --> Data Source Settings --> Edit Permissions --> Make sure all sources have the same Privacy Level.

Comment: I've reviewed the privacy settings and ensured all are equal.  Still encountering the error unless I insert an interim "extra" query.  But then I'm back to square one on executing the delay.

Comment: If privacy is not a concern set it to None for both.  If your ReviewPrep is a query that references another query as a parameter I think you have to flatten it and turn it into a single query.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/data-privacy-firewall (bottom example).